# Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, lintvitalrelease

Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
> Could not download intellij-core-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:27.1.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/27.1.0/intellij-core-27.1.0.jar'.
> > Tag mismatch!
> Could not download kotlin-compiler-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:27.1.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.1.0/kotlin-compiler-27.1.0.jar'.
> > Tag mismatch!
> Could not download groovy-all-2.4.15.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
> > Tag mismatch!

While building (generating signed app) at that time showing this error. few days ago tag mismatch problem occurred to me for gradle file so I replaced gradle `gradle-6.5-all` file then that error resolved for my all android projects but this one new error came. please friends help me to solve this problem. Anyone knows solution of this problem.